# webpack dev server Failed to load resource

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

The problem is that I get this very error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` when I use webpack-dev-server.
But if I just build the project then I can run my `index.html` and get the expected result.
My project structure is:

```
    public/
      index.html
      assets/
    src/
      index.js
```

> index.html

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>PBWA</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="assets/bundle.js"></script>
    </html>
```

And here're webpack config files

> webpack.common.js

```js
    const path = require('path')
    const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
    
    module.exports = {
      entry: './src/index.js',
      plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['assets'])
      ],
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/assets')
      }
    }
```

> webpack.dev.js

```js
    const merge = require('webpack-merge')
    const common = require('./webpack.common.js')
    
    module.exports = merge(common, {
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      devServer: { contentBase: './public' }
    })
```

> webpack.prod.js

```js
    const merge = require('webpack-merge')
    const common = require('./webpack.common.js')
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
    
    module.exports = merge(common, {
      devtool: 'source-map',
      plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin({ sourceMap: true }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        })
      ]
    })
```

So when I run `webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js` CLI command then I get the error.
And when I run `webpack --config webpack.prod.js` and then `open index.html` everything works just fine.
My question is why does webpack-dev-server behaves that oddly? What am I missing?

Comment: What happens here is that bundle.js is not generated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok the problem is solved. As far as webpack-dev-server doesn't actually create any files in project tree but loads them directly into memory and that's why we don't get `bundle.js` file in our `assets` folder. Next we use `devServer` in development mode and we set it's `contentBase` property which is to tell the server where to serve content from. But by default bundled files will be available in the browser under `publicPath` which is `/` by default. As far as we have assigned `assets` directory for this purpose we need to tell webpack to change it's defaults and assign `/assets/` to `publicPath` property of `devServer` options.
Finally, here's the code to solve the problem:

> in webpack.dev.js

```
...

devServer: {
  publicPath: "/assets/", // here's the change
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
}

...
```

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time! I am considering you as my friend now.